# SOQL: How to query for identical field values? ( SELECT form Object WHERE field1 = field2 )

Tags: soql

I found a redundant Owner field in an Org, which I want to check if it's matching the standard Owner field or not. A very simple SOQL query - at least I thought:

```
SELECT Account_Owner__c,OwnerId,Id,Name 
FROM Account
WHERE Account_Owner__c = OwnerId
```

But getting:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY:
WHERE Id = Name
ERROR at Row:3:Column:12
Bind variables only allowed in Apex code
```

Is it not possible in SOQL to match fields against other fields of the same record?

Comment: Workaround could be a comparison by formula field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not compare 2 fields in SOQL. You can do the check in code by doing something similar to this:

```
for ( Account a : [SELECT Account_Owner__c,OwnerId,Id,Name 
                             FROM Account
                             WHERE Account_Owner__c != null 
                             and OwnerId != null]) {

    if (a.Account_Owner__c != a.OwnerId) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Or you can add a boolean formula field called something like `AccountOwnerSameAsOwner` which returns true when both fields are the same. You will then be able to do the following:

```
SELECT Account_Owner__c,OwnerId,Id,Name 
FROM Account
WHERE AccountOwnerSameAsOwner__c = true
```

Comment: I see... just another of these strange SOQL limitations to trap into :-( - I am not in APEX just plain SOQL in workbech to have a quick glance.

Answer (score 0):

It's already answered here:

[Error in WHERE clause of SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14280/error-in-where-clause-of-soql)

> Unfortunately that query cannot be executed as written in SOQL since
>   SOQL does not allow direct field comparisons. I would recommend adding
>   a checkbox formula field to your object